# LoopbackJS version 3.x `Connection fails: MongoError: Authentication failed.`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I am trying to follow up the tutorial, I created a new app with lb, added CoffeeShop mode, then added a datasource, mongodb.
My MongoDB instance is on my local mac, and authorization is turned off.
I just run it with `mongod` command, no extra params, and there are no addition configs.

this is my datasources.json

```
 {
  "corp1": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 27017,
    "url": "",
    "database": "devdb",
    "password": "devpassword",
    "name": "corp1",
    "user": "devuser",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

I even created `devdb` database, and given devdb user to all databases as admin.
And still getting this error.

```
    Connection fails: MongoError: Authentication failed.
It will be retried for the next request.

/Users/hazimdikenli/learn/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:462
            throw err
            ^
MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/hazimdikenli/learn/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at /Users/hazimdikenli/learn/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:497:72
    at authenticateStragglers (/Users/hazimdikenli/learn/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:443:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/hazimdikenli/learn/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:477:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/hazimdikenli/learn/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:333:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

It am thinking that this is a newbie issue but I cannot find the problem. So please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not running mongod with --auth option, it still turned out to be an authentication issue, it worked after I executed following.

```
db.createUser({ 
    user : "devuser", 
    pwd : "devpassword", 
    roles: [ {role: "dbOwner", db: "devdb"}, 
             {role: "readWrite", db: "devdb"}]
})
```

before this, I granted roles on "admin" with this script, but looks like it was not enough.

```
role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin"
```